# Raw Input Inside If-statement?

Tags: python, if-statement, raw-input

Is there a way to use **raw input inside an if-statement**? I would like to ask the user a question and if they type "yes" I want to code to continue working after the if-statement. If they type "no" I want the code to say "Thank you for your time" and then **stop all actions after that particular if-statement**. Is this possible?

Code (I have never done this before so this is a wild guess):

```
    tri=raw_input("Do the points that you entered form a triangle? (yes or no)")  
    tri=str(tri)  

if tri == "yes" or "Yes" or "YES":   
    print "Your triangle is an:"  
elif tri == "no" or "NO" or "No":  
    print "Thank you for your time."  
else:  
    print "Not a valid answer, please try again later."
```

Comment: Definitely possible. Give it a shot and post some code then we can help you out.

Comment: try writing some code and see where you run into problems

Comment: Why not try and see?

Comment: I entered this code:

Comment: tri=raw_input("Do the points that you entered form a triangle? (yes or no)")
tri=str(tri)

if tri == "yes" or "Yes" or "YES":
    print
    print "Your triangle is an:"
elif tri == "no" or "NO" or "No":
    print
    print "Thank you for your time."
else:
    print 
    print "Not a valid answer, please try again later."

Comment: wait ignore that, ill post a second question and then put the link onto this one.

Comment: @ZachErickson there's an [edit] button just under the tags for your question. You can edit changes and clarifications into your question instead of posting a new one.

Comment: Sorry, new to this website. I already made the other question so here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36973488/raw-input-in-if-statement

Comment: @ZachErickson: In that case, delete this question.  Your other question is different enough that this question is no longer helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a shot:

```
tri = None
while tri not in ['yes', 'no']:
    tri=raw_input("Do the points that you entered form a triangle? (yes or no): ").lower()

if tri == 'yes':
    print "Your triangle is an:"
else:
    print "Thank you for your time."
```